# Tenir l’affiche meaning

Tags: verbes

What exactly does this mean and how is it used? Google tells me it means *to run*, and I’m assuming that’s not the same as *courir*. The latter I think refers to the physical act of running while the verb in question means to run as in a campaign, a show, something of that nature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ***affiche*** is a poster (of a show, a movie, a play), so the idiom

> ***tenir l'affiche***

means a show is "holding its poster", i.e. is currently running somewhere and has enough success to keep going day after day.

There are also the expressions:

> ***être à l'affiche***

which just means a show is running now, without giving any indication about its success and

> ***tenir/occuper/partager/quitter/... le haut de l'affiche*** ("to hold/occupy/share/leave/... the top of the poster")

which means that a show or a part of a show is the most successful of its kind, or a person has his/her name listed first on the poster of a show/movie, or is simply one of the leaders in some domain.

Comment: I had no idea such an idiom existed. Would it be translated literally, then, in a given phrase? i.e. _J’adore The Lion King, c’est vraiment tenir l’affiche !_ to mean _I love The Lion King, it’s really successful/holding its poster!_

Comment: *C'est vraiment tenir l'affiche* doesn't work. Moreover, *tenir l'affiche* means the show is effectively on stage/on display so the expression can't be used afterwards at the present tense. You might only say something like: ***Le Roi lion a tenu le haut de l'affiche plusieurs mois !*** or ***... a tenu l'affiche pendant cinq mois***. You also say ***La souricière (The Mousetrap) d'Agatha Christie est à l'affiche sans interruption depuis soixante-six ans***

Comment: "Tenir le haut de l'affiche" c'est être l'attraction principale d'un spectacle, soit en anglais *to headline a show*

Comment: @qoba Oui, c'est le sens original de l'expression mais elle est très souvent utilisée au sens figuré aujourd'hui.